# How to fetch Drupal entity from a webservice?

Tags: entities, 8

I'm building a rather special D8 website.

It will contain a lot of common node types (book, dvd, ebook, etc).
But - the data will not be fetched from the database, instead it will be fetched from a webservice (=WS).

The visitor will enter `http://example.com/book/[urlencoded-book-title]-[urlencoded-id-from-ws]`. Then the site will fetch the entity from the WS instead of the DB?

Is there a module that I can use to populate my entities from the WS?

The reason why I'm not saving in the DB is that there is over 50.000.000 records.

PS: I'm talking about loading a node content from the webservice and bypassing the database.

Comment: So, initialising a node object, for your twig template, but not saving it to the  database? It sounds like a strange approach, and would surely necessitate a bespoke module - why should the object be a node? Why not have your module create some kind of object to load in your twig template?

Comment: See this module https://www.drupal.org/project/external_entities